# How to find angle of rotation of barcode

Tags: image-processing, image-rotation, leptonica

I need to rotate back this below image to 0 degrees:

[image: Barcode image (+30 degrees)]

I tried using the **pixFindSkewAndDeskew** function of the **Leptonica** image processing library too, but it's returning the copy of input image. The output image, which I need, might look like this:

[image: Rotated back to 0 degrees]

My algorithm should rotate back images of any **orientation**.

What are the **limitations** of this function?

What kind of **input image** do I have to give to this function, for example high resolution image, etc.? What parameters should I consider to get the **deskewed** image?

Answer (score 0):

A histogram of the gradient direction should feature a peak showing the dominant direction. If that doesn't suffice, the Hough transform will return numerous segments in that direction.

Alternatively, you can apply a small number of rotations and try a read of the barcode until it works. If the reader is smart enough to tell you the code outline, you have the precise direction.

Comment: Yeah but how to use histogram data to find out angle in Leptonica. I thought to use Hough transform but i dint get similar function in Leptonica.

Comment: How to use **pixFindSkewAndDeskew** Leptonica function to deskew the image? Input image resolution is 1586x1603. What kind of input image should i use? I tried changing parameters defined in the function still din't work